# How to find elements that are in first pandas Data frame and not in second, and viceversa. python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have two data frames.

`first_dataframe`

```
id
9
8
6
5
7
4
```

`second_dataframe`

```
id
6
4
1
5
2
3
```

**Note:** My dataframe has many columns, but I need to compare only based on ID |
I need to find:

1. ids that are in first dataframe and not in second `[1,2,3]`
2. ids that are in second dataframe and not in first `[7,8,9]`

I have searched for an answer, but all solutions that I've found doesn't seem to work for me, because they look for changes based on index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `set` subtraction:

```
inDF1_notinDF2 = set(df1['id']) - set(df2['id']) # Removes all items that are in df2 from df1
inDF2_notinDF1 = set(df2['id']) - set(df1['id']) # Removes all items that are in df1 from df2
```

Output:

```
>>> inDF1_notinDF2
{7, 8, 9} 

>>> inDF2_notinDF1
{1, 2, 3}
```